# How to handle multiple xpath for same locator using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

How to handle multiple xpath for same locator using Selenium, i.e if one is failed use another locator for same field before failing script.

Comment: which language? what code have you already attempted to do so?

Comment: In JAVA language, looking for the best option that i can use

Answer (score 1):

To start with each [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) can be uniquely identified using any of the available [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890).

However, you can construct multiple [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) for the same element using permutation and combination of the available *attributes* and their values. As an example, for the element below:

```
<div class="_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text" data-tab="1" dir="ltr" spellcheck="true" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

You can construct multiple *xpaths* as follows:

1. `"//div[contains(@class, 'copyable-text')]"`
2. `"//div[contains(@class, 'copyable-text') and @data-tab='1']"`
3. `"//div[contains(@class, 'copyable-text') and @data-tab='1'][@dir='ltr']`
4. `"//div[contains(@class, 'copyable-text') and @data-tab='1'][@dir='ltr' and @spellcheck='true']"`
5. `"//div[contains(@class, 'copyable-text') and @data-tab='1'][@contenteditable='true']"`

All these *xpaths* would identify the same element. But what matters most is the *xpath* should be able to identify the desired element **uniquely**. The responsibility of constructing the **optimized** *xpath* is solely on the *test creator*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR` expression for the same. You can pass multiple attribute of the same `WebElement`.

For example:

```
Xpath=//*[@type='submit' or @name='btnReset']
```

Comment: Apart from this any other way?